# Eliminate consecutive counting in comparison lists

Tags: python, list, counting

I have dozens of lists that I need to compare to a main list.
What I need to do is compare each index value to the index value in the other lists.

Example:

```
list_1 = [8, 9, 14, 15, 7, 6]
list_2 = [3, 12, 10, 15, 8, 6]
```

Inside `list_1` as you can see in index 3 and 4, 14 is higher than 12 from `list_2`, and 15 is higher than 13, from this moment on this list should no longer continue to be compared because there are 2 indexes in consecutive that are higher than in `list_2`
but `list_2` is okay because there is no consecutive values being higher, index 1 (12) is higher than index 1 (11) in `list_2` but then in index 2 (10), the value goes back to being lower than in index 2 of `list2`.

The farthest I've gotten is doing a list comprehension like this:

```
compare = [i for i, j in zip(1_list, mainList) if i > j]
```

Or a loop:

```
for i, j in zip(1_list, mainList):
    if i > j:
        break
```

Any help?

Comment: What is this supposed to produce?

Answer (score 1):

You just need a flag.

```
already = False
for i, j in zip(1_list, mainList):
    if i > j:
        if already:
            print("Fail this list")
            break
        already = True
    else:
        already = False
```